# Mobile browser incorrectly interprets text as a callable phone number

Tags: mobile-website, phone-number

Does anybody know how to prevent mobile browsers from interpreting text as a phone number?  I have a serial number that is displayed as a link that calls some garbage number if selected.

Its all caps and looks like:  `200A (CDS100FG)`

I would like to flag it so it just shows as plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

works for iOS at least.

Comment: It works, thanks!

Just out of curiosity, if I did want to enter a valid phone number later on, is there a way to temporarily override this?

Comment: @n8thegr8 the solution is to avoid that meta tag and disable the format detection only on numeric texts that aren't phone number. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid disabling format detection for the Whole page, you can disable the format detection on numbers that aren't phone numbers (like VAT IDs), with that trick:

Specify the number 0123456789 as

```
01234<span>5</span>6789
```

For longer numbers, a span tag must be placed at least every six digits.